# rpm can't find configure no such file

Tags: configure, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a problem with my spec file. When I run it with rpmbuild it says it can't find ./configure no such file or directory. Here is a part of the code of my spec file. Can someone help me?

...

```
BuildRequires: gd-devel > 1.8, mailx, libjpeg-devel, libpng-devel

Requires: httpd php53 gcc

%description
Nagios is a program that will monitor hosts and services on your
network.
%package common
Group: Applications/System
Summary: Provides common directories, uid and gid among nagios-related packages
Requires(pre): shadow-utils
Requires(post): shadow-utils
Provides: user(nagios)
Provides: group(nagios)

%description common
Provides common directories, uid and gid among nagios-related packages.

%prep
%setup -q -n %{name}-%{version}
%build
%configure \
--prefix=%{_datadir}/%{name} \
--exec-prefix=%{_localstatedir}/lib/%{name} \
--with-init-dir=%{_initrddir} \
--with-cgiurl=/%{name}/cgi-bin/ \
--with-htmlurl=/%{name} \
--with-lockfile=%{_localstatedir}/run/%{name}.pid \
--libdir=%{_libdir}/%{name} \
--with-nagios-user=nagios \
--with-nagios-grp=nagios \
--bindir=%{_sbindir} \
--libexecdir=%{_libdir}/%{name}/plugins \
--sysconfdir=%{_sysconfdir}/%{name} \
--localstatedir=%{_localstatedir}/log/%{name} \
--datadir=%{_datadir}/%{name}/html \
--with-gd-lib=%{_libdir} \
--with-gd-inc=%{_includedir} \
--enable-embedded-perl \
--with-perlcache \
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `nagios`, but have you confirmed that when you extract the distribution tarball, there is a `configure` file in the top-level directory? If not, you need to add the steps to get there.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide your solution for others, who have a similar problem, like me